# How can I send pdf to client from API request

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, request, request-promise

I'm sending a request to an API that returns pdf files. I've tried `res.send(data)` but it doesn't work, and just returns a blank PDF file.

```
rp("URI")
    .then(data =>{
        res.contentType("application/pdf")
        res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

- Send is used for common HTTP response like JSON, XML, etc..
- To send files you need to call [`res.sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) with the `filePath` and its parameters

It looks like this

```
app.get('/file/:name', function (req, res, next) {

  var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/public/',
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
  };

  var fileName = req.params.name;
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi there! As i said, the pdf file comes from a external URI, not from my server. Still can I use readfile?